# How to serve an image/video from AWS S3 via express using the AWS v3 SDK

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to serve videos and images from a private S3 bucket. I can download the files from the bucket and when I download them directly via the web interface they work fine, but when I  use the SDK to server them using express I get a corrupted file. Currently, I use this code to fetch the file from S3:

```
export async function getObjectAsString(key: string): Promise<S3File> {

    const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_KEY_ID as string;
    const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY as string;
    const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME as string;

    const client = new S3Client({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
        },
    });
    const response = await client.send(
        new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: key,
        }),
    );

    // The code like below should really be provided as nice interfaces by the SDK itself.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!response.Body) {
            reject('No Body on response.');
        } else {
            const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
            const bodyStream = response.Body! as Readable;
            bodyStream.once("error", (error) => reject(error));
            bodyStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
            bodyStream.on('end', () =>
                resolve({
                    file: Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8'),
                    type: response.ContentType!,
                    length: response.ContentLength!,
                }),
            );
        }
    });
}
```

It's a slightly modified version of this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-1129709683

Then I use the result of that function in this express endpoint:

```
router.get('/media/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const file = await getObjectAsString(req.params.id);
    if (!file) {
        return res.status(404).send({error: 'File not found'});
    }
    writeFileSync('./img.jpeg', file.file); // I use this to debug, this will later be removed

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg').send(file.file);
});
```

As you can see I also tried just writing the output to a file, but that file also got corrupted, so my guess is that I'm not fetching the file correctly. Also, the `S3File` type looks like this:

```
type S3File = {
    file: string,
    type: string
    length: number
}
```

Comment: Have you considered simply sending the client a pre-signed URL for the S3 object so that your app doesn't have to proxy downloads from S3 (less reliably than S3 will serve them).

Comment: Yes, I guess that could work, but if I do that, wouldn't I loose on some metrics since I can no longer track how often an image had been requested. I mean once I generate the link and send it to user A can't they just share it with user B thus skipping my website?

Comment: Yes, they can share the link and it will be usable by someone else until the link expires. But they can also simply share the file itself with someone else. If you serve the file to the user, regardless of how you serve it, the user has a copy of it.

Comment: Yeah right. I guess the solution would then be to create a pre-signed URL and send that to the client with the 307/308 redirect status code. One small problem: If I just redirect them to S3, I won't be able to use Cloudflare for caching, right? So every request would be billed.

Comment: Using [CloudFront signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-overview.html#private-content-overview-edge-caches) would work. I have no hands-on with CloudFlare, but worth reading [this article](https://joshwright.com/tips/signed-s3-custom-secure-urls-on-cloudflare/).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)